# Finding a maximal complete subspace of Riemann Integrable functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, self-learning

I know that the space of Riemann Integrable functions on $[0,1]$ is not complete under the norm $|f|= \int f$. So I was wondering as to what would be a maximal complete subspace of Riemann Integrable functions.

My Try: Firstly I noticed that the subspace of constant functions is complete. So we know that the set of all complete subspaces is not empty. Now I would like to show that any chain of complete subspaces has a maximal element (I am having trouble showing this also I am not sure if this is true).

If we succeed then by Zorn's lemma there is definitely a maximal subspace. So we would have shown its existence.

Edit: I know that Lebesgue Integrable functions are in a way a completion of Riemann Integrable functions. So I was probably thinking we could take some subspace which is contained in Riemann Integrable functions then we would get some other spaces.

But I am wondering if we can actually write down the set.Any hints or comments are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The sequence $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of spaces of polynomials  of degree $\le n$ is an increasing sequence of closed subspace (e.g., because they are finite dimensional) whose union is not closed.

Comment: The polynomials are Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. Thus Jochen gave an example of an infinite chain of complete subspaces without maximal element. In fact, since the space of all polynomials is dense, there is no complete subspace of Riemann integrable functions that contains all these complete subspaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no maximal complete subspace in the space of Riemann-integrable functions.

In fact, given any non-complete normed space $X$, there is no maximal complete subspace in $X$.

To see this, asumme towards a contradiction that such a subspace exists; call it $E$. Then $E\neq X$ since $X$ is not complete. Take any $u\in X\setminus E$, and consider $F:= E\oplus [u]$, where $[u]$ is the $1$-dimensional subspace spanned by $u$. Let us show that $F$ is complete, which will contradict the maximality of $E$.

Consider the projection map $p:F\to [u]$ associated with the decomposition $F=E\oplus [u]$. The range of $p$ is $1$-dimensional, and the kernel of $p$ is $E$ which is a *closed* subspace of $F$ since $E$ is assumed to be complete. It follows that $p$ is continuous (using the well known fact that a linear functional is continuous if and only if its kernel is closed). So $Id-p$ is continuous as well. Hence, we have estimates $\Vert p(x)\Vert\leq C\Vert x\Vert$ and $\Vert x-p(x)\Vert\leq C\Vert x\Vert$ for $x\in F$. Since both $E$ and the $1$-dimensional space $[u]$ are complete, it now follows easily that $F$ is complete: if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $F$, then $(p(x_n))$ and $(x_n-p(x_n))$ are Cauchy in $[u]$ and $E$ respectively, etc.